# SQL Server stored procedure performance suddenly down

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which is loading a huge amount of data into a table. Suddenly it's run time has increased to a very high extent. Earlier it was taking ~2 minutes, now it's taking ~20 minutes. What could be the reason and how to debug the issue ? I am using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Index fragmentation or parameter sniffing can be the reason

Comment: How many rows in the target when it was fast and how many rows in the target when it was slow? Your first step is to undertake some very basic troubleshooting. For example install `sp_WhoIsActive` to see why it is taking so long